# How to change size of Terminal window during a tmate session (Linux)?

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

How to change size of Terminal window during a tmate session (Linux)?

Hello,

I am connecting from a client to a server over tmate (Linux)

[image: Terminal]

On the client side the Terminal window is full of small dots and a message in the bottom corner says "size 40 x 10 from a smaller client". Is there a way to resize the window so that it looks normal without all of these dots and so I can use the whole screen?

Vesa

Update: I need a solution that works without X

Comment: If you have installed, `wmctrl` can resize a window or make it fullscreen.

Comment: I think it requires X or something, right? wmctrl -l gives error message "cannot open display". (I do not have X and cannot install it on these machines).

Answer (score 0):

run "resize" before attach, like 
resize && tmate -S xxx attach

or press CTRL-B then capital "D" and kill old session